# Imprimir con json_encode un Array sale en doble

Tags: php, mysql, json, array

Al imprimir en json_encode un Array devuelto de una consulta MySql sale el resultado en doble:

primero muestra los resultados en base al numero array y luego lo muestraen array String

```
[

 {
  "0" : "Nombre",
  "1" : "Apellido",
  "idNombre" : "Nombre",
  "idApellido" : "Apellido",
 }

]
```

Consulta ::

```
$con = conexion();
    $consulta = $con->prepare("select * from nombres where Nombre='$genero' order by Nombre asc");
    $consulta->execute();
    $resultado=$consulta->fetchAll();
    return $resultado;
```

Imprimir ::

```
$consulta=nombres::genero($_GET['Genero']);
        echo json_encode($consulta);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Causa del problema

Eso es debido al *estilo de fetch* que se está aplicando sobre los datos.

Si lees la documentación, [`fetchAll()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php) (y los otros métodos `fetch` de PDO pueden recibir en parámetro uno de los *fetch style*  indicados [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php).

Cuando no se indica ninguno, PDO asume el método por defecto, que es `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` el cual devuelve los datos en forma asociativa y numérica, o el que tenga el objeto establecido en la configuración (que se puede hacer mediante `setAttributes()` o en el cuarto parámetro (opciones) que puedes pasar en el constructor.

## Solución

La forma más simple de resolver esta situación es indicando a `fetchAll()` de qué modo quieres los datos.

Si los quieres como array asociativo:

```
$resultado=$consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

En este caso los resultados serían:

```
[

 {
  "idNombre" : "Nombre",
  "idApellido" : "Apellido",
 }

]
```

Si lo quieres como array numérico:

```
$resultado=$consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

En este caso los resultados serían:

```
[

 {
  "0" : "Nombre",
  "1" : "Apellido"
 }

]
```

Queda claro que la forma de lectura de `$resultado` variará según el estilo que uses...

## Recomendación sobre la seguridad

Tu consulta es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Por norma, no pases nunca variables en las consultas. Un usuario mal intencionado puede manipularla y causar daños irreparables en varios niveles de tu sistema, no sólo en la base de datos.

En PDO es relativamente fácil blindar el código:

```
$con = conexion();
$consulta = $con->prepare("select * from nombres where Nombre=? order by Nombre asc");
$consulta->execute( array($genero) );
$resultado=$consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $resultado;
```

La consulta preparada en este caso consiste en cambiar el valor que pasabas directamente por un marcador `?` y el dato se pasa en forma de array en el método `execute()`. De ese modo PDO neutralizará cualquier intento de ataque.