# Aprender a recibir datos a través de Fetch con PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy tratando de aprender y entender como funciona `Fetch` y traer datos desde un archivo `.php` interno. No quiero hacer una API, simplemente me gustaría aprender y entender. No se si el archivo *PHP* esta bien y que debo tener en cuenta

Este es mi archivo **listado.php**

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM productos");
$sql->execute();
echo json_encode($sql->fetchAll());
exit();
```

**Resultado**

```
[{"idp":"1","0":"1","descripcion":"Marca Blanca Adulto G","1":"Marca Blanca Adulto G","preciounidad":"1200","2":"1200","stock":"49","3":"49"},{"idp":"2","0":"2","descripcion":"Marca Blanca Adulto XG","1":"Marca Blanca Adulto XG","preciounidad":"1500","2":"1500","stock":"35","3":"35"}]
```

Esto es lo que intento hacer con JavaScript que saque de [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) a modo de ejemplo y en la consola pudo ver los datos, pero no entiendo como se logra eso o como debo listarlos en el `.html`.

```
fetch('listado.php')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano y disculpen mi ignorancia.

Comment: Para listar los datos deberás recorrelos, lo puedes hacer con ciclo `forEach` y para mostrarlos tendrás que ver los template string (es mucho más fácil)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero que quiero señalar es que al usar `fetchAll()` sin indicar el *fetch style*, estás recibiendo los datos dos veces, como array asociativo y como array numérico. Generalmente en este tipo de resultados es más útil el estilo asociativo, porque puedes usar el nombre de la columna como información para identificar el valor asociado.

Para indicar el *fetch style* sólo tienes que pasarlo en parámetro a `fetchAll()`, por ejemplo:

```
echo json_encode($sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Para más detalles sobre los *fetch style* [puedes consultar el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php) así como [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/337551/29967).

En cuanto a la lectura de los resultados en Javascript hay varias posibilidades.

Si te interesa leer los valores y mostrarlos junto con su identificador, puedes hacerlo con [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

En el ejemplo he creado `data` a mano, dado que no estoy en tu contexto. Y, verás que los valores se repiten, asociados a identificadores de nombres y numéricos, por lo dicho antes sobre el *fetch style*.

```js
/*
  Estos son los datos que recibes
  Se ponen aquí manualmente para prueba
*/
var s='[{"idp":"1","0":"1","descripcion":"Marca Blanca Adulto G","1":"Marca Blanca Adulto G","preciounidad":"1200","2":"1200","stock":"49","3":"49"},{"idp":"2","0":"2","descripcion":"Marca Blanca Adulto XG","1":"Marca Blanca Adulto XG","preciounidad":"1500","2":"1500","stock":"35","3":"35"}]';

var data=JSON.parse(s);

Object.entries(data).forEach(([k,item]) => {
    Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
    });
});
```

En cambio, si te interesa mostrar sólo algunos datos, obteniéndolos por su nombre de propiedad, puedes hacer algo así:

```js
/*
  Estos son los datos que recibes
  Se ponen aquí manualmente para prueba
*/
var s='[{"idp":"1","0":"1","descripcion":"Marca Blanca Adulto G","1":"Marca Blanca Adulto G","preciounidad":"1200","2":"1200","stock":"49","3":"49"},{"idp":"2","0":"2","descripcion":"Marca Blanca Adulto XG","1":"Marca Blanca Adulto XG","preciounidad":"1500","2":"1500","stock":"35","3":"35"}]';

var data=JSON.parse(s);

Object.entries(data).forEach(([k,item]) => {
    console.log(`ID: ${item.idp}\nDescripción: ${item.descripcion}\n`);
});
```

El primer código te permite leer todo el objeto, sin necesidad de conocer de antemano el nombre de cada propiedad. El segundo código te mostraría valores específicos cuya propiedad conoces de antemano. En este segundo caso convendría asegurarte que esas propiedades existen.